# Uipath email activity for multiple email

Tags: uipath

Is it possible to have an array of email addresses (string) to pass into the send email activity on uipath? I can't see a way on the activity, except using the cc but I have 10 email addresses for he same email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple to addresses separated by the ; character.
The easiest way to do this is to use string.Join method and construct a string from the array.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create Variable ccMail like this

string ccMail="firstMail;secondMail;thirdMail;"

then pass this variable to CC in mail Activity

for Reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-sequence-project-for-sending-a-mail-using-smtp-activity-by-taking-crede/

Comment: Newer link is this one: https://docs.uipath.com/studiox/docs/send-mail-x